# Export dask to csv without csv quoting but quotes within columns

Tags: python, dask, quoting

I am trying to prepare billions of records with **Dask**. To later import them into influx db, the files need to be in format of in line protocol **as csv (or txt, dat, ...)** of the exact following structure:

**What I need:**
**['output-dask-to-csv-0.dat']**

```
weather temp=-6.73,air=963.7,prec=0.0,datetime="2011-01-01 00:00:13" 1293840013000000000  
weather temp=-6.74,air=963.7,prec=0.0,datetime="2011-01-01 00:00:13" 1293840013000000000 
weather air=963.7,datetime="2011-01-01 00:00:22" 1293840022000000000 
weather prec=0.0,datetime="2011-01-01 00:00:32" 1293840032000000000
```

I need to **get rid of the quotes** that occur automatically **at the beginning and the end** when I export dask to csv. At the same time need to **preserve the double quotes for datetime** with 1 empty space between date and time; as well as a comma separating entries in column fields; and empty space between columns measurement and fields, as well as fields and timestamp.

**Sample code:**

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import csv

measurement = ["weather", "weather", "weather", "weather"]
fields = ["temp=8.73,air=962.71,prec=4.0", "temp=4.12,air=963.2,prec=30.0", "air=964.21", "prec=0.0"]
datetime = ["2012-01-01 00:00:13", "2012-01-01 00:00:13", "2012-01-01 00:00:22", "2012-01-01 00:00:32"]
timestamp = [1293840013000000000,1293840013000000000,1293840022000000000 ,1293840032000000000]

d = pd.DataFrame(data={"measurement": measurement, "fields":fields, "datetime":datetime,"timestamp":timestamp})
df = dd.from_pandas(d, npartitions=1)
```

**For instance, what hasn't worked out so far and outputs the quotes at the beginning and at the end, as well as double quotes around datetime:**

```py
df['influx_format'] = df['measurement'] + ' ' + df.fields + df.timestamp.astype(str)
df.influx_format.to_csv(filename='output-dask-to-csv-*.dat', sep=" ", escapechar='"', header=False, index=0, decimal='.')
```

```py
"weather temp=-6.73,air=963.7,prec=0.0,datetime=""2011-01-01 00:00:13"" 1293840013000000000"
"weather temp=-6.74,air=963.7,prec=0.0,datetime=""2011-01-01 00:00:13"" 1293840013000000000"
"weather air=963.7,datetime=""2011-01-01 00:00:22"" 1293840022000000000"
"weather prec=0.0,datetime=""2011-01-01 00:00:32"" 1293840032000000000"
```

**I also couldn't get it to work with quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE:**

```py
df['influx_format'] = df['measurement'] + ' ' + df.fields + df.timestamp.astype(str)
df.influx_format.to_csv(filename='output-dask-to-csv-*.dat', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar="", sep=" ", escapechar='"', header=False, index=0, decimal='.')
```

```py
weather" temp=-6.73,air=963.7,prec=0.0,datetime=""2011-01-01" 00:00:13""" 1293840013000000000
weather" temp=-6.74,air=963.7,prec=0.0,datetime=""2011-01-01" 00:00:13""" 1293840013000000000
weather" air=963.7,datetime=""2011-01-01" 00:00:22""" 1293840022000000000
weather" prec=0.0,datetime=""2011-01-01" 00:00:32""" 1293840032000000000
```

Does anybody have an idea & could help me out?

Comment: @y.luis thanks for your comments about necessary edits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code gives me this:

> weather  temp=8.73,air=962.71,prec=4.0,datetime="2012-01-01  00:00:13"
>   1293840013000000000 weather 
>   temp=4.12,air=963.2,prec=30.0,datetime="2012-01-01  00:00:13" 
>   1293840013000000000 weather  air=964.21,datetime="2012-01-01 
>   00:00:22"  1293840022000000000 weather  prec=0.0,datetime="2012-01-01 
>   00:00:32"  1293840032000000000

```
df['influx_format'] = df['measurement'] + ' ' + df.fields + ',datetime=\"'+df['datetime'] + '\" ' + df.timestamp.astype(str)
df.influx_format.to_csv(filename='output-dask-to-csv-*.dat', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar="", sep=" ", escapechar=' ',header=False, index=0, decimal='.')
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Thank you! I think it is close.. when I try this code, for every space I have 2 empty spaces instead of just 1. Do you have an idea how I can fix that?

Comment: I just noticed it does not matter for my following approaches if there are two empty spaces between columns _measurement_ and _fields_, as well as _fields_ and _timestamp_, however, I can only have 1 empty space between date and time in datetime